# iOS companion app for Garmin CIQ devices

Tags: ios, garmin, connectiq

I'm trying to make an iOS companion app for my Connect IQ watch app. There already exists a fully functioning Android companion app, so I know that the watch app itself is ok.

I'm following the guidelines from the Garmin site, but my iOS companion app cannot connect to the watch app, or the watch itself. The watch is retrieved successfully through the Garmin Connect app, but any attempt to communicate with my watch app, or to open it (via `ConnectIQ.openAppRequest`) is unsuccessful. I'm receiving a "Device not available" error.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the **formatting** of the app id string. That requirement is not specified in the documentation, but the string should be formatted as `XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`. If the dashes are omitted, it won't work. Garmin has been notified of this.